# IOException when uploading image in android

Tags: php, android

Hi Iam trying to upload an image to server. But it is giving me IOException while uploading the image, which means the exception part is always get running. Pls help me how to resolve this problem.

Iam using the below code:

```
try {
                UpurlString = "http:/xxxxx/xxx/UpImage.php";
                length = fileInputStream.available();               
                //connectHTTP(UpurlString);
                url = new URL(UpurlString);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                Log.e("FilenameCheck",filename);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\""
                        + filename + "" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                buffer = new byte[8192];
                bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    sentData += bytesRead;
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);               
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();                        
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    while ((strResponse = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e("Response", strResponse);
                        /*if (strResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("The file " + filename
                                + " has been uploaded")) {                          
                        } else {                            
                        }*/
                    }
                    inStream.close();               
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: no error. only the exception part is running.05-29 09:17:31.728: E/Debug(11629): error: http:/xxxxx/xxx/UpImage.php

Comment: is there a `/` in the url `http:/webleads.usawebdept.com/IPhone/leadImage.php` after http:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `/` in the url `http:/webleads.usawebdept.com/IPhone/leadImage.php` after `http`

Comment: I have add the command as answer. please accept it as solution.

Comment: can u tell me ur gmail id? i have some more doubts in android.